# How to Register Node app with Spring Cloud and Netflix's Eureka

Tags: node.js, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, aws-api-gateway

I am trying hard to register my node app, with Netflix's Eureka , and after googling a lot, I am still looking for a solution . The max I can figure out is we have [Prana](https://github.com/Netflix/prana) but I got an issue which is still in the [issue list of Prana](https://github.com/Netflix/Prana/issues/18#issuecomment-146220600) (I guess it means my REST Template is not able to discover this app).

[Sidecar](http://techblog.netflix.com/2014/11/prana-sidecar-for-your-netflix-paas.html) , is another suggested solution , for which I am not getting any response . Apart from these two I have found a node module [Eureka-Node-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client) , but none of them serve my purpose .

Comment: Where are you not getting any response from regarding sidecar? Where is the question?

Comment: I see the sidecar you linked to is Prana, so disregard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a `Sidecar` application like you would create any `spring-boot` app:

```
@EnableSidecar
@SpringBootApplication
public class SideCarApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SideCarApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The important thing is that you have to configure it to correctly register your actual service. Your `application.yml` should look like this:

```
server:
  port: 9999 -- the port your spring-boot sidecar is running
spring:
  application:
    name: nodeapplication -- the name will be your id in eureka

sidecar:
  port: 8000 -- the node applications port
  health-uri: http://localhost:8000/health.json -- the exposed health eindpoint of your node application
```

It is important to note that the healthpoint should return `UP` so your services status will be correct in eureka. The returned json for a healthy service :

```
{
  "status":"UP"
}
```

If you are having trouble setting up a `spring-boot` app, use https://start.spring.io/ to configure a project. Sadly there isn't a sidecar option to tick, but you will get the idea. You can do the same from `STS` (Spring Tool Suite).

The maven dependency for `Sidecar` (with spring-cloud as a parent):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-sidecar</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How to set health.json file ?

Comment: I am having difficulty with @EnableSideCar.  Is there an import that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [eureka-js-client](https://github.com/jquatier/eureka-js-client) which can be directly used in the node application to register with eureka.

Comment: Would eureka-js-client be used in addition to sidecar?

Answer (score -1):

I used the npm generator-express-sidecar to generate a gradlew sidecar project with all the out-of-box configurations
Please refer to the reference link shared below
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-express-sidecar

Comment: Please do not post "link only answers". The second the link breaks, the answer becomes useless. At least provide a summary of the link content.